# How do you get the values from a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I am very new to the Javascript and I am wondering how I can get the values from a function.

From my given code I would like to get the values of TheName, TheHeight, and TheGender, TheSexuality when I run the function so that I can use them for other purposes in my program.

Code:

```
function prng ()
{
    var Name = Object.values(person.Names);
    var Height = Object.values(person.Heights);
    var Gender = Object.values(person.Genders);
    var Sexuality = Object.values(person.Sexualities);
    var TheName = Name[Math.floor(Math.random() * Name.length)];
    var TheHeight = Height[Math.floor(Math.random() * Height.length)];
    var TheGender = Gender[Math.floor(Math.random() * Gender.length)];
    var TheSexuality = Sexuality[Math.floor(Math.random() * Sexuality.length)];
    console.log('Name: ' + TheName + ', Height: ' + TheHeight + 
    ', Gender: ' + TheGender + ', Sexuality: ' + TheSexuality);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: That's not a function. Use [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) to return values. If you need to return multiple values from the same call, wrap the values in an array or an object and return that.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that cause I have no idea :)

Answer (score 0):

you write something like that:

function nameYourFunction ()
{
...
instead of console.log(...) you write:
return 'Name: ' + TheName +...+ TheSexuality;

}

or you add all varibles to one object like that:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can define object inline and return it like this

```js
    function prng ()
    {
        var person = {Names:'xx' , Heights:123,Genders:'male',Sexualities:'',};
        var Name = Object.values(person.Names);
        var Height = person.Heights;
        var Gender = Object.values(person.Genders);
        var Sexuality = Object.values(person.Sexualities);
        var TheName = Name[Math.floor(Math.random() * Name.length)];
        var TheHeight = Height[Math.floor(Math.random() * Height.length)];
        var TheGender = Gender[Math.floor(Math.random() * Gender.length)];
        var TheSexuality = Sexuality[Math.floor(Math.random() * Sexuality.length)];
        return {Name : TheName ,Height: TheHeight, Gender:TheGender,Sexuality: TheSexuality};
    }

    var v = prng();
    console.log(v);
```